# How do I add waits to my Selenium scraping program?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, anaconda, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape a website and save the information using Python and Selenium.  The scrape is simple, and only requires choosing the state and district in two dropdown menus, clicking a submit button, and reading and writing a table to a csv.

I am confident my packages are installed correctly and my program even works, but only some of the time.  My guess is that without the proper Selenium driver 'waits', my program crashes because it can't find the correct css_selector.  I'll post the program below, and if anyone has any suggestions on how to correctly incorporate Selenium driver 'waits', I would very much appreciate the help.

Thanks so much, and here's the program:

```
import time
import re
import string
import urllib.parse
import pandas
import numpy
import os
import csv

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
url = "https://myhpgas.in/myHPGas/HPGas/LocateDistributor.aspx"
driver.set_window_size(1120, 550)
driver.get(url);
time.sleep(5) 
stateList = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlState")
options = stateList.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")

optionsList = []

for option in options:
    optionsList.append(option.get_attribute("value"))

optionsList[1:len(optionsList)]
for optionValue in optionsList:

    select = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlState"))
    select.select_by_value(optionValue)
    districtList = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlDistrict")
    distOptions = districtList.find_elements_by_tag_name("option")

    distOptionsList = []

    for distOption in distOptions: #iterate over the options, place attribute value in list
        distOptionsList.append(distOption.get_attribute("value"))

    for distOptionValue in distOptionsList[1:len(distOptionsList)]:

        distSelect = Select(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlDistrict"))
        distSelect.select_by_value(distOptionValue)
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ContentPlaceHolder1_btnShowList').click()
        data = []                      
        for tr in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#ContentPlaceHolder1_gvDistributor'):
            tds = tr.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')
            if tds: 
                data.append([td.text for td in tds])
        print(data)
        dataRows = int(numpy.array(data).size / 7)
        rowsTimesColumns = (dataRows * 7) -1
        newArray = numpy.array(data)
        outArray = newArray[0:rowsTimesColumns]
        test = pandas.DataFrame(outArray.reshape(dataRows,7), columns=['no', 'distributor', 'address','contact1', 'contact2', 'contact3', 'map'])

        file_path = 'Users/outpath' + '_' + optionValue + '_' + distOptionValue + '.csv'
        test.to_csv(file_path, sep=',')
        driver.back()
    driver.back()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you tell me which line returns an error!? Also how about using xpaths!?

I couldn’t see the statement to implement explicit waits

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located_by(By.CSS_SELECTOR,*your css selector*))
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Siddharth! I discovered the source of my error, and it invovled not adding optionsList = optionsList[1:len(optionsList)] on line 30.  You are correct, there was not a statement to implement explicit waits.  However, I will implement the line of code you suggested.  Also, why do you suggest using Xpaths over CSS selectors?  I will make the change if you think Xpaths are superior.  Best, Dave

Comment: Well using xpaths it’s more like a habit. I personally find them easier to implement and locate. Actually css selectors are faster,boils down to person preference.